# changing the CSS property of parent div in inner div element

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div and the overflow property in my CSS is defined as hidden.

However the child div which is wrapped inside the parent div and I am positioning the child div absolute with respect to my parent div and show it on top of the page using top:something.

However the child div is not visible on the page since the overflow property of parent div is set as hidden.

It looks something like this

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
overflow: hidden;
}

#child {
position: absolute;
top: -290px;
left: 0px;
bottom: auto;
z-index: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

How to I make the child div visible without setting overflow property of the parent div as visible.

Comment: why u use top:-290px; ??

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer, **you cant.**

If you're setting `overflow:hidden` on the parent, it will do just that to any overflow so so not show the child.

Regardless, if the parent `div` is aligned to the top of the viewport, because the child has `top:-290px` it will not be shown as it renders outside the viewable space of the browser window (namely 290px before it begins).

You may need to think about what you're trying to accomplish and why.

In order to correctly show child content outside the defined boundaries of a parent, consider giving the parent fixed height/width (optional) with a position of `relative`. The child should be positioned absolutely within this, but can be placed outside its limits. It will display as long as `overflow:hidden` isnt set on the parent, and the child's position remains within the browser viewport.

## See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vSYKC/1/) for examples

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. The parent div has position relative already. The parent div is a container inside the page (below header and navigation menu which in total sums up the height around 290px from the top pf the page) that's why I had to give the child element top -290px in order to show the child div on top of the page (above every other element on the page).

Comment: I'm afraid if you're using overflow hidden, what you're after cant be done. You may want to see whether the structure you're using is the best approach

Comment: Give me a moment I will add a screenshot. Might give you an better idea what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Please have a look at the screenshot what I am trying to accomplish

http://imgur.com/XiLXzKS

Comment: Structurally it makes no sense for your child element to be nested within its current parent. Its impossible to say without the HTML of the whole page, but the child looks like it should be a standalone part at the very top of the body

Comment: I completely agree with you. The problem is I am creating static breadcrumbs and placing it on every html page of the website. If I include the static breadcrumb on the default decorator of my site which would include the breadcrumb on the top irrespective of other elements on my page, but it wont make the link change since I am not fetching page URL dynamically. Every other HTML page in my site in called under the main container as you can see in the screenshot. So I had to put breadcrumb code in individual HTML instead of the decorator.

Comment: I don't see any other option at the moment which would solve my problem so I will just change the overflow:hidden to visible on my parent div and set the breadcrumb div position:absolute and top:-290px.

Comment: Other than rethinking the overall structure, that is you're only option unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

overflow: hidden; is not the actual reason for hiding child div. Minimize the `top: -290px; to top: 0px;` and child div will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Top:-290px; value. Because it will go outside the limit.

Comment: Please find my comment above. If I set the top value lets say 0 it will be relative to my parent div not with the html body